# How to make translucent glossy soap-like material?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

Hi thanks for your help!!
I spent 4 days trying to make this soap but I don't feel satisfied with the result. What can I do?
I tried to add volumetric absortion but it didn't provide good enough result either.

Reference photos:

[image: real photo]

Rendered result:

[image: blender render]

Comment: Welcome to the site. One of your images seems to be missing, so I edited your question. Also provide some info about your rendering engine and material settings you use (you can comment to your post instead of editing it with links). Thanks.

Comment: translucent is mostly definitely something you'll need, and I would use Fresnel to adjust reflective level from different angle. SSS node is something worthy of trying if translucent doesn't give you what you want. Try not to use volumic absortion, I hated it, personal opinion. Your first render looks pretty close actually. Most importantly, do not drop it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mr Zak and SVAFnemesis, taketh on its recommendations, and i'll post a new render with my final result. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Soap]

This is closest I can get. It is kind a partial answer but it could be starting point for you.

I've used fot this Subsurf Scattering shader added to Translucent shader and then mixed with Glossy shader by Fresnel to give it fake PBR look.

**Here is a node setup:**

[image: nodes]

**And .blend file:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank's all of you for your quickly help! and thanks LukeD to take your time and give me the blend file, I am indebted to all of you!!!

Comment: @FaustoServellon If my answer was good enough, consider accepting it or/and upvoting ;)